# Use custom dataset instead of MNIST for GAN

Tags: keras, deep-learning, dataset, mnist, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to work with a simple Generative Adversarial Network (GAN) based on this [code](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN). The example of GAN in that code is using the MNIST dataset

```
# Load the dataset
(X_train, _), (_, _) = mnist.load_data()
```

Can you help me how to change the `mnist.load_data()` to my own custom dataset?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for loading a bunch of images from a directory:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
def load_images():
    normalize = lambda x: (x.astype('float32') - 127.5) / 127.5 # normalize to between -1: and 1
    data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=normalize, zoom_range=0.2, 
                                  horizontal_flip=True,rotation_range=0.05)

    x_train = data_gen.flow_from_directory(INPUT_DIR,
                                            target_size = (IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE),
                                            batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                            shuffle = True,
                                            save_to_dir='augmented',
                                            class_mode = 'input',
                                            subset = "training")

    return x_train

x_train = load_images()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you have solved this or not, but I will try to provide an answer. First of all `mnist.load_data()` can not be changed to your own custom dataset, it contains the `mnist` data. 
To further help you, I will need insights into what "your own" data set is?

When I have been using "my own" datasets I usually store them in NumPy arrays this way I know the structure and I can just use `numpy.load()`.