# Using custom data instead of MNIST for GAN

Tags: keras, dataset, mnist, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to run the code about GAN in [this link](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/master/dcgan/dcgan.py) with my own dataset in Colab. For this, I need to load my own dataset like in the next line

```
(X_train, _), (_, _) = mnist.load_data()
```

I know this question has been asked before [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60149834/use-custom-dataset-instead-of-mnist-for-gan). But when I tried the solution in csteel's comment, I am getting the error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'DirectoryIterator' and
> 'float'.

As I understand it this solution allows me to navigate in the directory I want. However, I am getting the error I mentioned. I didn't understand exactly what to do.